# Is there such a thing as a type C USB 2.0 connection?

Tags: usb, tablet, usb-2

I came across a tablet yesterday, which advertised a type-C USB micro port, but never mentioned USB 3.0 or USB 3.1. Later, I searched more and the reviews actually said it was a USB 2.0. Is there any point to this? I mean does having USB type-C (at this stage) add any value at all to the device?

EDIT: My question is to why a manufacturer would want to do (except to advertise) this or why a user would want to buy this.

Comment: It can probably charge faster. However, without knowing the exact make and model, further elaboration is impossible.

Comment: One point might be that it works with the newer cables (which can be inserted both ways).

Comment: definitely it'll be cheaper than a USB 3.0 compliant device

Answer (score 3):

Type-C specifications define the new connector form-factor, which includes receptacle, plug, and a set of various cables. It is designed to serve all USB protocols, and is not a subject of whether it is possible on not. Just as a Type-A host receptacle can carry USB2-only connection (which is indistinguishable from USB3 receptacle except its color, which is infrequently black as in usual USB2), developers of products with Type-C connector can choose to use only wires for USB2, and implement USB2 protocol only. Or they can choose to implement no USB protocol at all, using new Type-C means for charging only (CC, Communication Channel pins). The choice is dictated by cost versus sufficient functionality of a OEM device.

Type-C adds significant value to OEM products due to its ability to be orientation independent, regardless if it carries USB2, USB3, or only charging signature (which is another advantage).

Unfortunately yes, manufacturers frequently resort to ambiguity and fail to mention explicitly which particular USB protocol they have implemented over Type-C connector. It is very inconvenient for end users and deceptive. This probably should fall under a category of false advertising, with proper legal consequences.

Answer (score 2):

USB type C is a physical interface specification as where USB 2.0 is a protocol specification, so technically it would be possible to run USB 2.0 over USB type C (the terminology is very confusing). I would doubt any manufacturer would run anything less than USB 3.1 over USB-C.

Speculating as to why they would've done it (if they even have, docs are also faulty sometimes); USB C connectors can be plugged in both ways, and allow for more amps to run through the cable, resulting in faster charging.

Answer (score -2):

One possible reason for OEMs to only support USB 2 with a USB-C connector is the underlying platform. Not all platforms support USB 3 yet.

If an OEM wants to ship a product with USB-C (could be for various reasons, such as compatibility with newer cables, marketing value, reversibility of the plug, etc) but builds it on a platform which only supports USB 2, then a combination of the USB 2 protocol with a USB-C connector is the easiest solution (in comparison to including an additional chip that supports USB 3).